# Error attempting to load font file from VS form application resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm encountering an "IndexOutOfRangeException" on the `ff = pfc.Families[0];` line when trying to load my .tff font file from my VS form application resources.  You think you could look at my code and tell me why and how to fix it?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr AddFontMemResourceEx(IntPtr pbfont, uint cbfont, IntPtr pdv, [In] ref uint pcFonts);

        FontFamily ff;
        Font font;

        bool NameFieldPopulated = false;
        bool TitleFieldPopulated = false;
        bool LocationFieldPopulated = false;
        bool ExtFieldPopulated = false;
        bool OutputFieldPopulated = false;
        public static string NameInput;
        public static string DirName;
        public static string TitleInput;
        public static string LocationInput;
        public static string PhoneNumber;
        public static string ExtensionInput;
        public static string DirInput;
        public Form2 overwrite;
        public SucessForm success;
        public OverwriteSucessForm succ2;
        public MainForm main;


        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GenerateButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void loadFont()
        {
            byte[] fontArray = SF_Signature_Generator.Properties.Resources.bignoodletitling;
            int dataLength = SF_Signature_Generator.Properties.Resources.bignoodletitling.Length;

            IntPtr ptrData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(dataLength);

            Marshal.Copy(fontArray, 0, ptrData, dataLength);

            uint cFonts = 0;

            AddFontMemResourceEx(ptrData, (uint)fontArray.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref cFonts);

            PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

            pfc.AddMemoryFont(ptrData, dataLength);

            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrData);

            ff = pfc.Families[0];
            font = new Font(ff, 15f, FontStyle.Regular);

        }

        private void AllocFont(Font f, Control c, float size)
        {
            FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;

            c.Font = new Font(ff, size, fontStyle);
        }


        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadFont();
            AllocFont(font, this.NameLabel, 20);
        }
}
```

Comment: The top Google hit for AddMemoryFont() has a very nasty bug.  You must not call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() until the font can no longer be used.  Typically you do so after calling PrivateFontCollection.Dispose().  Which is very rarely done correctly as well, never releasing it is the better solution.  You just need to make sure that this font is only loaded once.

Comment: hmmmmm, so is the code i'm using not the correct way of going about this?

Comment: My suggestion, keep your collection alive - as a Field or whatever - and call `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem();` after you have added the font to the collection. Or, as Hans says, don't call it at all. You can call [RemoveFontMemResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162921(v=vs.85).aspx) in the end. Or don't call it at all. See the Docs about it.

Comment: I'm still getting the exception even if I comment out the line :(

Comment: `AddFontMemResourceEx` returns an `IntPtr`. You should check whether the Font was actually created. If not, you get back `IntPtr.Zero` and `cFonts == 0`.

Comment: If you get IndexOutOfRangeException then the logical conclusion is that the font you used is not usable.  Which is not uncommon, System.Drawing does not support OpenType fonts.  Another basic way to check this is to install the font with Control Panel > Fonts and verifying that it shows up in the dialog when you try to modify the form's Font property.